# How to define overflow-y?

Tags: jquery, css

I don't understand why it doesn't like my `overflow-y` syntax?

[image]

```
function show_modal(target){
    $(target).modal({
        backdrop: true,
        keyboard: true
    }).css({
        width: 'auto',
        overflow-y: 'hidden',
        'margin-left': function () {
            return -($(this).width() / 2);
        }
    });
    $(target).modal('show');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DOM exposes CSS properties as camelcased versions of themselves. Try using `overflowY` instead.

As a general note, to put a hyphen in an object key name, you need to use quotes:

```
{
    "width": 'auto',
    "overflow-y": 'hidden',
    "margin-left": function () {
        return -($(this).width() / 2);
    }
}
```

<strike>I am not sure if jQuery automatically maps the CSS names to the corresponding DOM versions, so it is best to use `overflowY` instead.</strike>

As Chris Heald has pointed out, jQuery does in fact accept the hyphenated property name as well as the camel cased one, so either of `overflow-y` (provided you use quotes) or `overflowY` should work.

Comment: Quoted `overflow-y` and `overflowY` both work fine in jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

`overflow-y` is overflow minus y, which is a syntax error since the key part of an object literal must be either an *identifier*, a *string literal*, or a *numeric literal*, not an *expression*. To use the overflow-y property, you can quote the property name into a string literal like so: `'overflow-y': 'hidden',`